# Online Website Refers On Client's Time or WHERE?

Tags: php

I set the timezone of the website `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');`

This is still done on localhost so the time will really base on my computer's time.

Since I manually set the timezone of the website; when it goes online, on which time will the website base? Will it always be GMT+8 or the hosting's time or it will base on the user's time? Will the set timezone be kept or the hosting's time or something will overwrite it?

I'm really confused what will happen to the timezone if the website goes online.

Answer (score 0):

If you show the date through PHP, you will be showing the server time.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_date.asp

Answer (score 0):

It would consider the server's timezone and according the timezone you have set, it would add or subtract hours. If you have on server machine time `2015-05-25 12:00:00.000000` and it is `UTC+08` and you set `UTC+04` on you app, you would get time like `2015-05-25 08:00:00.000000`